# Merge multiple column rows into a single cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column that looks like this

```
A
B
C

D
E
```

I need to turn this column into rows, each empty cell marking new row, looking like this:

```
ABC
DE
```

Is there an easy way to do this in Excel?

Comment: Using only Excel, you have to copy every block of letters and then you need to paste them with transpose each time. I don't think it could be done in one step without using macros.

Comment: Transpose not working very well in this case as I have over 500k cells separated with empty cell in that one column and that needs turning into rows after each empty cell.

Comment: Too many cells for using transpose so yes, need a macro then.

Answer (score 1):

If you copy the code below in a module it should do what you are asking for (make sure the sheet with your data is the active sheet). There are no checks for data validity - it assumes that:

- the sheet with data is the active sheet,
- there is data in Column A

and it outputs the result in column B.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub doIt()

   Dim data As Variant
    Dim result As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    data = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    ReDim result(1 To UBound(data, 1), 1 To 1) As Variant

    j = 1
    For i = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
       If data(i, 1) = "" Then
          j = j + 1
       Else
          result(j, 1) = result(j, 1) & data(i, 1)
       End If
    Next i

    With ActiveSheet
        .Cells(1, 2).Resize(UBound(result, 1), 1) = result
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach, uses the AREAS() method, perfect since your groups of data are separated by blank cells.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ColumnToRows()
Dim RNG As Range, a As Long

    Set RNG = Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlConstants)

    For a = 1 To RNG.Areas.Count
        RNG.Areas(a).Copy
        Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
    Next a

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

If column A is not full of constants, you can change that to **xlFormulas**.